# Stepwise refinement using for loops/ no output using Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using this code to display the output commented in below.

```
public String drawCore(int star, int hash)
{
String output = "";
for(int i=0; i<star; i++)
{
    output += this.drawStar(star);
    for(int j = 0; j<hash; j++)
    {
        output += this.drawHash(hash);
    }
    for(int k = 0; i < star; k++)
    {
        output += this.drawStar(star);
    }
}
return output;
 //intended output (assuming parameters entered are 1 for star and 2 for hash:
 // *##*
 //actual output
 // (nothing)
 }
```

While my original question was whether the code

```
for(int i=0; i<star; i++)
    {
        output += this.drawStar(star);
        for(int j = 0; j<hash; j++)
        {
            output += this.drawHash(hash);
        }
        for(int k = 0; i < star; k++)
        {
            output += this.drawStar(star);
        }
            }
```

could be better designed to where I would not have the same loop to drawStar before and after the loop for drawHash, when I try running the code in Eclipse, I am not getting any output.

Here are the drawStar and drawHash methods if you're wondering if there's a problem in them.

```
public String drawSpaces(int num)
{
    String output = "";
    for(int i=1; i<num; i++)
    {
        output+= " ";
    }
    return output;
}

public String drawHash(int num)
{
    String output = "";
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        output += "#";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Also, I don't think it's a problem with the console because when I try to run the Driver class which just includes the code

```
 public class AsciiArtDriver
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     AsciiArt ChryslerBuilding = new AsciiArt();
     System.out.print(ChryslerBuilding.draw());
     }
 }
```

The intended output is correct, however when my Driver class looks like this

```
public class AsciiArtDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    AsciiArt ChryslerBuilding = new AsciiArt();
    System.out.print(ChryslerBuilding.drawCore(1,2));
    }
}
```

the output is nothing.

Please help!! Thank You!

Comment: Is the `drawSpaces()` method above what you meant to post?

Comment: @anthonyW No I didn't sorry about that. the actual method for drawStar is essentially the same, just inside the for loop of drawStar would be output += "*" rather than " "

Comment: Why are you nesting your `drawStar()` and `drawHash()` methods in additional for loops? It should be sufficient to say `drawStar(star)`; `drawHash(hash)`; `drawStar(star)`;

Comment: Also, watchout for your `drawSpaces()` method. If you pass it a 1, it will give you an empty `String` and not a space.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

In your `drawCore()` method you say `for(int k = 0; i < star; k++)`. Notice the `i` in the middle. The reason you are not seeing any output at all is that your code is stuck in an infinite loop. Changing that statement to `for(int k = 0; k < star; k++)` gives you an output of `*####*`. To get the desired output see below.

---

Solution: Take out the extra loops.

```
public String drawCore(int star, int hash) {
    String output = "";
    output += drawStar(star);
    output += drawHash(hash);
    output += drawStar(star);
    return output;
}
```

---

Beyond the basic solution of taking out the extra loops, I would refactor that code to use a StringBuilder (for performance) and further to use a common `repeat()` method to handle the looping:

```
public String drawSpaces(int num) {
    return repeat(" ", num);
}

public String drawHash(int num) {
    return repeat("#", num);
}

public String drawStar(int num) {
    return repeat("*", num);
}

public String repeat(String s, int num) {
    if(s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```